# Setting up a global error handler in a bootstrapped firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception, error-handling, firefox-addon

I am building a bootstrapped extension for Firefox (not using the Add-on SDK since I need tcp sockets). Although all my IO calls etc. are protected by a try/catch, I want to have a global error handler just in case. Bootstrapped extensions do not have access to a window object so the window.onerror route is out of the question. Any suggestions as to how I can go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a reliable global error handler. Just wrap `startup`/`shutdown` (`install`/`uninstall`) in `try-catch` blocks. You may also want to wrap global statements.

```
try {
  // do some fancy initialization... But you really shouldn't at the global scope.
}
catch (ex) {
  // handle/log error, e.g.
  Components.utils.reportError(ex);
}

function startup() {
  try {
    // Run
  }
  catch (ex) {
    // handle/log error, e.g.
    Components.utils.reportError(ex);
  }
}
function shutdown() …
// etc.
```

The extension manager will log failures with your bootstrap.js anyway (see the `extensions.logging.enabled` preference).

Aside: SDK add-ons can use the [`chrome` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) to gain access to low level stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have `try/catch` blocks in startup and shutdown as you have suggested. But they can only catch exceptions taking place during startup and shutdown, respectively. Since most of the work takes place via several asynchronous background callbacks and listeners, they won't be able to catch any stray/uncaught exceptions. On Chrome, every app gets it's own background page, so `window.onerror` works. I shall go through the chrome module and see if it can solve my issue.